# Make a dataframe with str.count() over the index

Tags: python, pandas, count

**EDIT** (thanks to **Jezrael** to lead me on a way to do it):

I have a list of phone numbers, and I'd like for every number to count the number of occurences of each digit. You'd understand that a double `for` loop isn't possible as I have a few hundred thousands phone numbers to compute on.

For that i create a dataframe (because I feel it might be an effective way to do it) which contains on each row the split of the phone number:

```
numbers = ['0615260518','0815465948','0215616235','0415291826']
df = pd.DataFrame([list(number) for number in numbers])


Out[1]:
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   0   6   1   5   2   6   0   5   1   8
1   0   8   1   5   4   6   5   9   4   8
2   0   2   1   5   6   1   6   2   3   5
3   0   4   1   5   2   9   1   8   2   6
```

Then I need to fill it with the desired counts. Desired output:

```
Out[2]:
            0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0615260518  2   2   1   0   0   2   2   0   1   0
0815465948  1   1   0   0   2   2   1   0   2   1
0215616235  1   2   2   1   0   2   2   0   0   0
0415291826  1   2   2   0   1   1   1   0   1   1
```

Here is a bloody not pythonic way to achieve it:

```
for num in df.index:
    for col in df.columns:
        df.ix[num,col] = num.count(str(col))
```

Way too long to compute, then Jezrael offered me this solution:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(), axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Which is way better, but still too long. So I've tried to replace the value_counts which isn't designed for small dataframes:

```
df.apply(lambda x: digit_count(''.join(x)), axis=1)
```

Where:

```
def digit_count(number):
    my_string = list(number.lower())
    my_dict = []
    for i in np.arange(10):
        my_dict.append(my_string.count(str(i)))
    return my_dict
```

Which is about 3 times faster. But is there any way to do it even faster (I feel this iteration isn't optimal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first convert `index` [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html), because [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) does not work with `index` yet. Last [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and cast to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
a = (df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))))
print (a)
            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0615260518  0  6  1  5  2  6  0  5  1  8
0815465948  0  8  1  5  4  6  5  9  4  8
0215616235  0  2  1  5  6  1  6  2  3  5
0415291826  0  4  1  5  2  9  1  8  2  6

print (a.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(), axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int))

            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  8  9
0615260518  2  2  1  0  0  2  2  1  0
0815465948  1  1  0  0  2  2  1  2  1
0215616235  1  2  2  1  0  2  2  0  0
0415291826  1  2  2  0  1  1  1  1  1
```

EDIT:

```
from collections import Counter
print (pd.DataFrame([x for x in a.apply(Counter, axis=1)]))
   0  1    2    3    4  5  6    8    9
0  2  2  1.0  NaN  NaN  2  2  1.0  NaN
1  1  1  NaN  NaN  2.0  2  1  2.0  1.0
2  1  2  2.0  1.0  NaN  2  2  NaN  NaN
3  1  2  2.0  NaN  1.0  1  1  1.0  1.0
```

**Timings**(`len(df)=4`):

```
In [288]: %timeit (a.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(), axis=1))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.74 ms per loop

In [289]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame([x for x in a.apply(Counter, axis=1)]))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.27 ms per loop
```

(`len(df)=4k`):

```
In [296]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame([x for x in a.apply(Counter, axis=1)]))
10 loops, best of 3: 87 ms per loop

In [297]: %timeit (a.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(), axis=1))
1 loop, best of 3: 2.45 s per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't actually need to keep the index, so for the first step, the following seems way more efficient: a = pd.DataFrame([list(number) for number in numbers]).
As for the second part, it still takes about 3 minutes to compute, isn't there a faster way?

Comment: Perfect, the counter way is great for this problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for upvoting too. Nice day.